# Insert cookie/flash-cookie from external domain / cross-domain. API

Tags: api, cookies, cross-domain, tracking

I need to track visitors.

I have a script (http://example.com/something.aspx) that saves all the visitor data (like browser, referrer, etc.) into a DB and insert a flash-cookie in the visitor machine for further tracking.

Right now I insert that script using an iframe in each page I want it to work.

The script need to be in the same domain of the page for it to work.

I use this script in a number of domains, so for each domain I have the same script installed in each domain.

I want to provide some kind of javascript API to be able to use only one script for all the domains. "One Script to Rule them All".

Its important to know that I own all the domains.

It is possible? How to achieve cross-domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following approach, but have not tested the whole thing.

insert  into the page.

The record-and-set-cookie.aspx page will record agent info into a database (this part I am sure will work), and then return javascript that will set a cookie (this part can work, but needs confirmation).

Comment: Well, it's not helping me. How to achieve cross-domain?